# MLB Winning Pitcher Determination

Tags: mlb

During the 1960's could the Official Scorer in a MLB game decide who the winning pitcher was if he pitched 7 or 8 innings and left with the game with the score tied 1-1 if his team later scored the winning run in the 9th inning?  I know this is not the case now, but thought it was back in the 1960's.

Comment: I don't think the methodology has changed since then.  If his team scored the winning run before another pitcher took over (starter pitched through the end of the 8th, reliever took over at the start of the ninth, team scored in between those two events), then he'd get credited with the win.  If they scored in the bottom of the 9th and the reliever pitched the top of the ninth, then the reliever would get the win.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a rulebook of that era, but I've not heard of this before.

[Baseball Almanac](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/rulechng.shtml) has a page listing major rule changes over the years.  As this seems quite "major" to me, I'd expect it to appear there.  I see several mentions of changes to the save rule, but not for wins and losses.

A copy of a relevant rulebook would be best, but short of that I'm leaning to "no, there doesn't seem to have been a change in this rule since the '60s"